# Javascript associative array problems

Tags: javascript

i have a function

```
var myarr[] =new Object();
  function myfunction(id,msg)
 {
    myarr[id,msg]
 }
```

I am trying to add msg with id as a key...but its not working...plz help

Comment: var myarr=[];
and 
myarr[id]=msg;

Comment: Thanks giys...it worked the braces with my arr was a typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is:

Declaring myarr:

```
myarr = {};
```

Adding an item:

```
myarr[id] = msg;
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to sort it as well...based on the id which is a string and not an int??

Comment: @abbas: You cannot sort object properties, they are unordered. I suggest you read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and make yourself familiar with the difference between arrays and objects.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is not Java.

The following function will create an array consisting of objects.

```
var myarr = []; //Or: var myarr = {};
function myfunction(id, msg) {
    var obj = {};    //Create object
    obj[id] = msg;   //Set property with key=id, with value=msg
    myarr.push(obj); //Use `push` method of the array to insert object in an array
}
```

If you want to create a single object, and set properies using key=id, and value=msg, use:

```
var myarr = {};
function myfunction(id, msg){
    myarr[id] = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean:

```
function myfunction(id,msg)
 {
    myarr[id] = msg;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't included the brackets `[]` when declaring a variable as an Array or Object in JavaScript.

```
var myarr = new Object();
```

Secondly, you need to adjust your assignments:

```
myarr[id] = msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how to create associative arrays. Herei s a jsfiddle with the correct functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/qRuWz/